# how to fix error like "required and installed (@@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)"

Tags: centos, repository, rpm, yum

I have to hosts (server that has repository called amescom) and client that use server repository to download and install rpms and packages
when i try to update repository using yum update command from client host , it gives me the following error:

```
Package: coreutils-8.4-31.el6.x86_64 (amescom)
           Requires: coreutils-libs = 8.4-31.el6
           Installed: coreutils-libs-8.4-19.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               coreutils-libs = 8.4-19.el6
Error: Package: e2fsprogs-1.41.12-14.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
           Requires: libss = 1.41.12-14.el6
           Removing: libss-1.41.12-14.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               libss = 1.41.12-14.el6
           Updated By: libss-1.41.12-18.el6.x86_64 (amescom)
               libss = 1.41.12-18.el6
Error: Package: cronie-anacron-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
           Requires: cronie = 1.4.4-7.el6
           Removing: cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               cronie = 1.4.4-7.el6
           Updated By: cronie-1.4.4-12.el6.x86_64 (amescom)
               cronie = 1.4.4-12.el6
Error: Package: e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-14.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
           Requires: libcom_err = 1.41.12-14.el6
           Removing: libcom_err-1.41.12-14.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               libcom_err = 1.41.12-14.el6
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.41.12-18.el6.x86_64 (amescom)
               libcom_err = 1.41.12-18.el6
Error: Package: ca-certificates-2013.1.95-65.1.el6_5.noarch (amescom)
           Requires: p11-kit >= 0.18.4-2
Error: Package: db4-utils-4.7.25-17.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
           Requires: db4 = 4.7.25-17.el6
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-17.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               db4 = 4.7.25-17.el6
           Updated By: db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64 (amescom)
               db4 = 4.7.25-18.el6_4
Error: Package: coreutils-libs-8.4-19.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
           Requires: coreutils = 8.4-19.el6
           Removing: coreutils-8.4-19.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               coreutils = 8.4-19.el6
           Updated By: coreutils-8.4-31.el6.x86_64 (amescom)
               coreutils = 8.4-31.el6
Error: Package: ca-certificates-2013.1.95-65.1.el6_5.noarch (amescom)
           Requires: p11-kit-trust >= 0.18.4-2
Error: Package: nss-tools-3.14.0.0-12.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
           Requires: nss = 3.14.0.0-12.el6
           Removing: nss-3.14.0.0-12.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               nss = 3.14.0.0-12.el6
           Updated By: nss-3.15.3-3.el6_5.x86_64 (amescom)
               nss = 3.15.3-3.el6_5
Error: Package: nss-softokn-3.14.3-9.el6.x86_64 (amescom)
           Requires: nss-softokn-freebl(x86-64) >= 3.14.3
           Installed: nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               nss-softokn-freebl(x86-64) = 3.12.9-11.el6
Error: Package: e2fsprogs-1.41.12-14.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
           Requires: libcom_err = 1.41.12-14.el6
           Removing: libcom_err-1.41.12-14.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4)
               libcom_err = 1.41.12-14.el6
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.41.12-18.el6.x86_64 (amescom)
               libcom_err = 1.41.12-18.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: For some time now I've been having a problem with the coreutils upgrade too - getting the following:

coreutils-libs-8.4-31.el6_5.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with coreutils-libs-8.4-31.el6.x86_64
coreutils-libs-8.4-31.el6_5.1.x86_64 has missing requires of coreutils = ('0', '8.4', '31.el6_5.1')
librsvg2-2.26.0-6.el6_5.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with librsvg2-2.26.0-5.el6_1.1.0.1.centos.x86_64
openldap-2.4.23-34.el6_5.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
openldap-devel-2.4.23-34.el6_5.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with openldap-devel-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `amescom` repo contains some packages but not its dependencies. E.g. it contains `db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4` but not required `db4-utils-4.7.25-18.el6_4` so you get the above dependency problems. Check this output to see all the db4 and db4-utils version-releases available:

```
yum list db4\* --showduplicate
```

You might also want to ask repository administrator to run [repoclosure](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/repoclosure.1.html) on the repo (or you can do it yourself) to see if all packages in the repo have its dependencies available there as well.